# edittext addtextchange listener reapeting text

Tags: android, android-textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

i've seen so many example but no one work for me. what i want is to set text to the TextView through the EditText's addTextChangeListener(). but my textview text is repeating for each character i typed in edittext.

here i my code:

```
edtFromName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            private String lastValue = "";
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setMessage();
            }
        });

// setMessage code:
  private void setMessage() {

        if (refVia.getSelectedItemPosition() < 3) {
            if (txtCompany.equals("")) {
                txtText.append(" or ");
            } else {
                txtText.append(" " + txtCompany + " or ");
            }
        } else {
            if (txtSupplier.equals("")) {
                txtText.append(" or ");
            } else {
                txtText.append(" " + txtSupplier + " or ");
            }
        }

        txtText.append(edtFromName.getText().toString() + ".");
    }
```

output:

```
Edittext:  sagar

textview: s
textview: sa
textview: sag
textview: saga
textview: sagar
```

Comment: repeating in the sense. What is your input and what is output?

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for appending.

```
int mainStringLength = txtText.getText().toString().length();
int nameStringLength = edtFromName.getText().toString().length();
String trimString = txtText.getText().toString().substring(0,(mainStringLength - nameStringLength); 

//Now set this string.
txtText.setText(trimString);
```

Comment: sorry.. but this is not my solution.. i m not only set edittext value.. i have other autocomplete text also. that's why i m use append.

Comment: thank you shabbir.. its worked.. but there is some problem with other text, but i will manage it.. after all you gave me an owesome idea..

Comment: great that solution help you. consider upvote too :)